# Bootstrap validation and Bootstrap select

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Two really good bits of UI for Bootstrap 3.

Firstly, to validate field forms, the validation found here - http://bootstrapvalidator.com/

Secondly, the default style of the select element isn't great, I've used various methods in the past to style the select, however, usually come across browser render issues - this plugin works great with bootstrap - http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

So I was quite happy with the above... until I tried using them together. The validation won't work (green tick fails to appear) when using the selectpicker to style the select.

Can these work in sync, if so, how!?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the documentation for the Bootstrap validator? It mentions the Bootstrap Select plugin:

http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-select/

It seems to suggest they work together. If you're still having problems, it might be worth posting your code or a Bootply.

---

**Edit:** Sorry, I've just realised how old this post is (I found it on the newest questions bit, so didn't check), so I imagine it wasn't in the documentation then! I'll leave my answer anyway, just in case anyone stumbles across it asking the same question.